# set screen orientation on startup Debian stretch

Tags: touch-screen

Using Debian Stretch. My computer starts with the screen sideways. I can set it right with xrandr -o 0 but this only works for the session. Using rc.local does not work because X session is not running then.

Can I somehow set the default screen orientation so that the login screen and following are oriented correctly across sessions?

Comment: How is your screen set up (resolution, size, display make, video card)? Do you have a widescreen display that is mounted on its side or something similar? Framebuffer display rotation is possible, but if there's a lower-level solution I prefer to use that.

Comment: The computer is an ASUS Monitor is InfoVision LCD monitor graphics card is Intel Atom /Pentium Processor x5 Integrated Graphics Controller. Size 12" Aspect Ratio is 16:9 Resolution is 1366 x 768

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `fbcon` module in your kernel (this is usually the case), then you can control screen rotation for text mode using that. Per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237963/how-do-i-rotate-my-display-when-not-using-an-x-server) (for Ubuntu, but it's generally applicable):

1. First, make sure that `fbcon` is working:

   `$ echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/graphics/fbcon/rotate`

   (or `rotate_all` to affect all virtual framebuffers; valid values are `0` through `3`, starting normally and rotating 90° clockwise for each additional number.)
2. If the rotation works, add or edit the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` (or `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` if you're paranoid) line in `/etc/default/grub`:

   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="fbcon=rotate:1"`

   (replace `1` with whatever value worked for you.)
3. Run `sudo update-grub` (or whatever you use to update your `grub.cfg` configuration).

If your computer boots [using EFI](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68369/rotate-console-on-startup-debian), you may need to add `video=efifb` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`.

Comment: The  sudo tee /sys/class/graphics/fbcon/rotate does not work because rotate is not a directory.   fbcon is a link to /../devices/virtual/graphics/fbcon  
So i could not test. Tried fbcon=rotate:0...3 in this command but that did nothing just returned to the prompt. 
fbcon appears to be there OK but testing it before editing GRUB was not possible .... so far

Comment: OK so I tried the update to grub but that had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Make a script, start it with `#!/bin/bash` and add the command which fixes your screen. Then add the script in crontab so it gets executed on every boot:

```
crontab -e @reboot path_to_script/name_of_script.bash
```

This will allow your fix to be automatically applied as PC boots.